# Check if the user name is entered in EditText already exists in the SQL database. - Android

Tags: android, sql

I want to check if the user name is entered in EditText already exists in the SQL database.

For that create a new String with the content of the EditText.

```
user = nombreUsuario.getText().toString().trim();
```

Create a method to read all users of the database and the contents of the cursor also pass a String.

```
public String obtenerNombresDeUsuario() {

    String lectura = "";
    Cursor c = db.query(TABLA_BASEDATOS, new String[] {KEY_NOMBRE, }, null, null, null, null, null);

    int nom = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NOMBRE);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        lectura = c.getString(nom) + '\n';

    }
    return lectura;
}
```

Then use the method. Contains () to see if the database name already exists, but does not work.

```
if (duplicado.contains(user)){
    //Creamos el aviso
    Toast aviso = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El nombre de usuario ya existe, por favor seleccione un nombre de usuario distinto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    aviso.show();
}else{
    //insertamos el nombre de usuario en la base de datos
    db.insertarContacto(user, "0");
    db.cerrar();
}
```

any suggestions to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (c.moveToFirst(); c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
```

I think should be

```
for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
```

Do you only want one name to come back from this? At the moment you are looping, but resetting the lectura value every time.
You can use

```
lecture += c.getString(nom) + '\n';
```

If there are going to be lots of Strings, you might want to use a String builder.

```
public String obtenerNombresDeUsuario() {

    Cursor c = db.query(TABLA_BASEDATOS, new String[] {KEY_NOMBRE, }, null, null, null, null, null);

    int nom = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NOMBRE);

     StringBuilder lectura = new StringBuilder();
     for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        lectura.append(c.getString(nom) + '\n');

     }
     return lectura.toString();
}
```

You can also check to see if the lectura exists just using sql

```
public boolean lecturaExists(String lectura) {

    Cursor c = db.query(TABLA_BASEDATOS, new String[] {KEY_NOMBRE, }, "lectura_name = ?", new String[]{lectura}, null, null, null);

    int nom = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NOMBRE);

    boolean exists = c.moveToFirst();
    c.close();
    return exists ;
}
```

Comment: I do not know how to do it, just try to adapt the code i see on the internet to my application. could you show me some example pls?

Comment: Thank you very much, with your corrections it works.
To be an amateur i was not so lost :P